# How to maintain communication among Multi window Angular App

Tags: rxjs, angular5

I am creating an angular app which has two components, one takes some input and the second shows it in real time with the help of the `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators.

Now I need to dock one component out to new browser window, so I can drag that component to another monitor screen.

I am using `window.open()` for docking out the component to new window, but it breaks the communication as it bootstrap a new app in that new window.

Is there any mechanism to keep the communication among multiple windows?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.postMessage` to communicate between windows.

As you are using `window.open`, you will be able to get a reference to the window to communicate with.

Be careful to also handle security concerns with `postMessage` to ensure you are receiving events from the correct source.

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage